# reparenting streams in perforce

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate

I have the following stream hierarchy

A -> B -> C

A is parent of B, B is parent of C. I am currently working on stream C. 
Stream B is soon going to get defunct and I need to merge C to A. What's the best possible way to go about this?

a) Re-parent stream C : Make A new parent of C. Is this safe?

b) Create a workspace off A and merge C directly to A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge from A to B and B to C (so C is fully up to date with A), and then it should be trivial to reparent C to A.  Reparenting difficulties are mostly the result of having a lot of divergence between the stream and its new parent.